# Which version of javassist is compatible with java 8?

Tags: java, javassist

I am currently on`JDK 1.6`. I am using ApacheMina's `javassist-3.18.1.GA.jar` and I want to migrate to `JDK 1.8`. I would like to know if `javassist-3.18.1.GA` is compatible with `JDK 1.8` or not.

If not, then which version of javassist can be used that is compatible to `JDK 1.8` ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In that case, if you are still wondering, then `javassist-3.18.2.GA` is surely compatible with jdk 8.

Comment: Based on what is your answer?

Comment: Based on the release notes though, I'd go with 3.19.0.GA if you can: `Including a number of bug fixes and Java 8 supports.` https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases

Answer (score 1):

`Javassist 3.18.1.GA` is used in `JBoss EAP 6.4` which is compatible with `Java 8`.